# How to join database tables in my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Here is my code:

**albums.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.AlbumsModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Albums</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Album ID</th>
                <th>Artist ID</th>
                <th>Artist name</th>
                <th>Album title</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Album album in Model.Albums)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@album.AlbumId</td>
                    <td>@album.ArtistId</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelArtists => album.Artist.Name)</td>
                    <td>@album.Title</td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Details" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumId">Details</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Edit" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumId">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/Delete" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumId">Delete</a></td>   
                    <td><a asp-page="/Albums/AlbumTracks" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumId">Tracks</a></td>       
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <p>Enter a title & ArtistID for a new album:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Album.Title" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Album.ArtistId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

**AlbumTracks.cshtml**

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.AlbumTracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Track name</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                    <td>@track.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@* <div class="row">
    <p>Enter a name & TrackID for a new track:&nbsp;</p>
    <form method="POST">
        <div><input asp-for="Track.Name" /></div>
        <div><input asp-for="Track.TrackId" /></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</div> *@
<div>
    <a asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
</div>
```

**AlbumTracks.cshtml.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Project.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Project.Pages
{
    public class AlbumTracksModel : PageModel
    {
        private Chinook db;

        public AlbumTracksModel(Chinook injectedContext)
        {
            db = injectedContext;
        }
        public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
        public void OnGetAsync()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
            Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album);
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I'm displaying *all* tracks from *every* album in AlbumTracks.cshtml, instead of just the one selected by the user on album.cshtml. I've read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) repeatedly, but I'm struggling to work out the syntax for AlbumTracks.cshtml, and maybe I need something more in AlbumTracks.cshtml.cs?

I think maybe I need to use something like this to join the tables:

```
        if (item.AlbumID == Model.AlbumID)
```

Any pointers please? TIA.

Edit: [GitHub repo](https://github.com/double-happ1ness/chinook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the moment I'm displaying all tracks from every album in AlbumTracks.cshtml, instead of just the one selected by the user on album.cshtml.

Are you sure what you describe is correct? You display all the tracks from all the albums by using the following code:

```
Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album);
```

I think what you want is that you can display the selected album's tracks when click the `Tracks` link in `albums.cshtml`:

```
<td><a asp-page="/Albums/Album Tracks" asp-route-id="@album.AlbumId">Tracks</a></td>
```

If what I said is correct, you need firstly add `id` parameter to your `/Albums/AlbumTracks` method and modify the linq like below:

```
public class AlbumTracksModel : PageModel
{
    private Chinook db;

    public AlbumTracksModel(Chinook injectedContext)
    {
        db = injectedContext;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Track> Tracks { get; set; }

    public void OnGetAsync(int id)
    {
        ViewData["Title"] = "Chinook Web Site - Tracks";
        Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album).Where(a=>a.AlbumId==id);
    }
}
```

AlbumTracks.cshtml:

```
@page
@using Project.Models
@model Project.Pages.AlbumTracksModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<div class="row">
    <h1 class="display-2">Tracks</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-inverse">
            <tr>
                <th>Track name</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            @foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@track.TrackId</td>
                    <td>@track.Name</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but there's one or more things here I'm not quite getting. IDK what you mean by 'Are you sure what you describe is correct?' The AlbumTracks.cshtml page definitely shows all tracks from all albums as things stand. I've updated AlbumTracks.cshtml.cs with `Tracks = db.Tracks.Where(a=>a.AlbumId == id).Include(a => a.Album);`. That's the table join, right?? But now how do I get the tracklisting for the selected album to actually display on AlbumTracks.cshtml? I don't know what syntax to use. https://github.com/double-happ1ness/chinook

Comment: That's the table join. What do you mean for do not know what syntax to use?  Just using `Tracks = db.Tracks.Where(a=>a.AlbumId == id).Include(a => a.Album);` is enough in backend.  And your client side used: `@foreach (Track track in Model.Tracks)`.  `Tracks` here match the backend `Tracks`. That is to say it will read the backend data and display it in your AlbumTracks.cshtml. Did you try in your project?

Comment: I have updated the AlbumTracks.cshtml. Actually it is the same as yours. I think you may do not have time testing my code in your project.

Comment: Ah, that's brilliant, many thanks. I didn't at first see the difference with `Tracks = db.Tracks.Include(a => a.Album).Where(a=>a.AlbumId==id);`. I thought my version was just doing the same thing, but for some reason I don't understand it clearly isn't. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
foreach (var track in Model.Tracks)
{
    if(item.AlbumID == Model.AlbumID)
    {
         <tr>
              <td>@track.TrackId</td>
              <td>@track.Name</td>
         </tr> 
    }
}
```

could you maybe post your models?

I had something similar in my app, I created 2 models e.g. 1 for tracks and 1 for albums.
then in your Album model make a list Tracklist and in your track model make a property AlbumId.
In your trackcontroller, upon creating a track you could have something like

```
var albums = _context.Albums.toList // or any other way to retrieve the albums from the DB. 
foreach (var item in albums)
if (track.AlbumId = item.Id)
{
     item.Tracklist.add(Track)
}
```

I'm still kinda new to this so hope this works!

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason that gives me error 'The name 'track' does not exist in the current context'. When you say models do you mean the entity files? Album.cs & Track.cs? Or the context file Chinook.cs?

Comment: I tried it again, but this time I'm getting 'The name 'item' does not exist in the current context' & ''AlbumTracksModel' does not contain a definition for 'AlbumId' and no accessible extension method 'AlbumId' accepting a first argument of type 'AlbumTracksModel' could be found'

Comment: Could you maybe post a link to your github repo or source code? I meant adding the Id to album.cs and AlbumId to Track.cs. then in package manager console perform: add-migration and update-database. this will add the columns to your database, next empty your database and fill it with new testdata and link the tracks with their album by setting the AlbumId for each track to the corresponding Id of the album, let me know if this helps

Comment: The GitHub repo is at https://github.com/double-happ1ness/chinook . To be clear, `AlbumId` already exists as both the primary key of the Album table and the foreign key of the Tracks table, so I'm almost entirely certain that nothing further needs to be done with the database. Right now I'm 'pulling' the data I need with `Tracks = db.Tracks.Where(a=>a.AlbumId == id).Include(a => a.Album);`. I *think* that is right as the landing pages use `id` as the parameter. But then how do I get the tracks to actually display on the AlbumTracks.cshtml page?